# Key Up/Down Selection of Autocomplete list in Textbox C#

Tags: c#, list, autocomplete, textbox, key

In C# Winforms, I have a textbox with AutoCompleteMode. When the user types some letters the suggestion list populates Correctly. However, if an item in list is selected using (Keyboard) UP and Down key it could not navigate through the list of items. it just picks up the first item shown in the list.

On the other hand selection using mouse click works fine. here is my code

```
    private void txtQryName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> fullName = _customerBll.NameSuggestor(txtQryName.Text);
        AutoCompleteStringCollection source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        source.AddRange(fullName.ToArray());
        txtQryName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        txtQryName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        txtQryName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with having a key based selection is that it is very sensitive to the number of items it the stack contains. A possible solution could to be to set that KEY_UP and KEY_DOWN only increase/decreases or selects a specific type within the list.

Additionally I believe you can set the textbox to have a specific responds when you press it, you should consider that if for example the user has not choose an item within ( BOOLEAN: false or true) than no items are selected

An example

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress
(object sender,System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // Check for the flag being set in the KeyDown event.
    if (nonNumberEntered == true)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx

Here is some useful stuff for you if you want to expand upon this idea. Hope my answer helps